# Using OKTA - CORS Error After Upgrading to Spring Boot 3 - CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cors, okta

I have an application with Vue.js in the front end and Spring Boot for the back end.  We use OKTA for security.  This has been working great with Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.1.8.

The Spring Boot REST services are http://localhost:7801 and the NGINX server for the UI is http://localhost:7800.

Recently, I am attempting to upgrade the back end to use Spring Boot 3.1.3 and Java 17.  I get the following error when the UI accesses an end point:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

After updating Spring Boot, there were some required changes to Spring Security.  Otherwise the back end code is identical.  I do have http://localhost:7800 and http://localhost:7800/ configured in OKTA as Trusted Origins.

After researching this I am still not sure how to make this work.  I appreciate any ideas.

**Spring Boot 2.1.8**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2Client()
            .and().oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry
                    .addMapping("/api/myapp/**")
                    .allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:7800");        
        }
    };
}
```

**Spring Boot 3.1.3**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class OAuthSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http              
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()                      
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

         // done
        return http.build();
    }
```

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:7800"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/myapp/**", configuration);
    return source;
} // end corsConfigurationSource()
```

**Request Headers**

```
OPTIONS /oauth2/authorization/okta HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7801
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Referer: http://localhost:7800/
Origin: http://localhost:7800
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 07 Sep 2023 12:45:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Console**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Comment: This is still an open and unsolved issue.  I am going to open a support ticket with OKTA.  I'll update this with any suggestions they have.

Comment: After working with OKTA support and additional debugging, this was resolved by adding .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())); to the security config, and removing oauth2Client() and ouath2Login().  Spring Boot 2 we had oauth2Client() and ouath2Login() and all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You might try defining a `FilterRegistrationBean` like we did in our [Build a Simple CRUD App with Spring Boot and Vue.js tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/build-crud-spring-and-vue/).

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // *** URL below needs to match the Vue client URL and port ***
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:8080"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

We use something similar in [JHipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/WebConfigurer.java.ejs#L177).

FWIW, you don't need `@EnableWebSecurity` on your security configuration class if you're using Spring Boot. You only need `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your conf allows cross origin requests to `/api/myapp/**` only and the failing request happens to `/oauth2/authorization/okta`

Also, instead of:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http              
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()                      
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())

        ...

        return http.build();
    }
```

try:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, CorsConfigurationSource source) throws Exception {
        http              
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(source))
                .csrf(configurer -> {
                    final var delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
                    delegate.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
                    // Adapted from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework
                    configurer.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).csrfTokenRequestHandler(delegate::handle);
                    http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
                }).authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/login/**", "/oauth2/**", "/actuator/**").permitAll()                      
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    private static final class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException,
                IOException {
            CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            // Render the token value to a cookie by causing the deferred token to be loaded
            csrfToken.getToken();

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

this will:

- pick the `corsConfigurationSource` bean you already defined and explicitly inject it in your security filter-chain
- enable protection against CSRF attacks
- allow anonymous access to the URIs used during the login process (so, before the user is successfully authenticated)

With this modified CORS configuration source `@Bean`:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:7800"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/myapp/**", configuration);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth2/**", configuration);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/logout", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

This will:

- allow `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` requests too (and make your intentions clearer, probably).
- allow CORS requests to some missing path
- enable user credentials are support

##### P.S. n°1

Seems that you forgot to `permitAll()` access to `/login/**` and `/oauth2/**` which are used during the login process.

##### P.S. n°2

OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login` must be protected against CSRF attacks: requests authorization is based on sessions which are the vector for CSRF attacks. **Do not disable CSRF**.

##### P.S. n°3

If you were using `spring-cloud-gateway` in front of both your Vue.js app and your Spring API, all requests would have the same origin: the gateway => no more CORS config needed.

The other benefit would be that you could configure the REST API as a stateless resource server (with CSRF protection disabled) while still using a "confidential" OAuth2 client and keep tokens on your servers only. I have a tutorial for configuring `spring-cloud-gateway` as such a BFF [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff). The frontend is written with Angular, but as all that is required regarding authorization is [setting `window.location.href`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/fba24d58ab1c0aa22d48e51b3d0a3b6bfa3932e7/samples/tutorials/bff/angular/projects/bff-ui/src/app/user.service.ts#L39), you should be able to port it to Vue.

This makes me strongly recommand you do introduce a BFF between your Vue.js app and your REST API:

- use `spring-cloud-gateway` as stateful OAuth2 client with login and CSRF protection and `TokenRelay` filter
- switch your REST API to resource server configuration (stateless and disabled CSRF)

The layer with sessions will be thinner and your overall architecture will scale much better.

Comment: I tried using configurationSource as you suggested and get the same result.  I had actually tried this earlier.  So I still get Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.  This seems to be with the OPTIONS method with http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta.

Comment: I am pretty sure that my CORS config is getting picked up.  If I remove it or change something I get an error on my actual end point instead of http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta.

Comment: Wait, what is the request that fail (to which host and with which method)? Please check in your browser debugging tool to be sure that it's an `OPTIONS` request to `localhost:7801` that fail. Also see my updated answer with `setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"))` to allow `HEAD` requests too.

Comment: I added the allowedMethods as you suggested.  I edited my posting to include info from the network and console tabs of my browser.  You can see that it is failing on an OPTIONS method for http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta.  As this is working today with Spring Boot 2.x, I wonder if there is something I am missing when using Spring Boot 3 with OKTA.

Comment: Hadn't paid attention to path: it seems that you allow CORS requests to `/api/myapp/**` only and the failing request is to `/oauth2/**` (you need to allow **`permitAll()`** CORS requests to `/login/**` and `/oauth2/**` for `oauth2Login` to work)

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I can add that to the CORS config.  I have tried it.  End up with other errors.  So, that doesn't fix it.  I am happy to do that and post the results if you are interested.  I appreciate all the effort here.  Unless you have some other ideas, I may end up opening a ticket with the OKTA team.

Comment: See my updated comment about `permitAll` to `/login/**` and `/oauth2/**` (used during `oauth2Login`, so before user is identified)

Comment: OPTIONS
http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403

Comment: 2023-09-07T11:18:21.118-04:00 DEBUG 15992 --- [nio-7801-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@1c6ce2f4
2023-09-07T11:18:21.119-04:00 DEBUG 15992 --- [nio-7801-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:7801/oauth2/authorization/okta
2023-09-07T11:18:21.166-04:00 DEBUG 15992 --- [nio-7801-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing OPTIONS /oauth2/authorization/okta

Comment: I made the changes you suggested.  I would be curious why this would be needed in Spring Boot 3 and not version 2.x.  Anyway, see my comments above.  This fails with OPTIONS for /oauth2/authorization/okta, even though I added permitAll() to /oauth2/**

Comment: Update your question with your new conf and error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255208/discussion-between-user925406-and-ch4mp).