# CORS Issue When Accessing Spring Authorization Server's /oauth2/token from another client

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I'm currently implementing an SSO solution using Spring Authorization Server and an Angular client. I've successfully obtained an authorization code, JWT access token, and refresh token using Postman, but when I try to make the same request from my Angular client to the /oauth2/token endpoint, I encounter CORS errors.
Here's a snippet of my security configuration:

```
@Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain apppFilterchain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector)
            throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        http.formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/login").permitAll());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/logout")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/hello")).permitAll().requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/login")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth2/token")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/*")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/***")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/webjars/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/auth/**")).permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated());
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf((csrf -> csrf.disable()));
        return http.build();
    }
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        config.addAllowedOrigin("https://client2");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

And I have a CORS filter to handle CORS headers:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public CORSFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        log.info("Response Header adding");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

I've already ensured that the client is running on https://client2, and I've added config.addAllowedOrigin("https://client2") in my CORS configuration. However, I'm still stuck with this issue.

I have this error in my browser console

> (Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domain/name/oauth2/token?client_id=clientid&redirect_uri=https://redirect/uri&grant_type=authorization_code&code=x5qQ7-####&code_verifier=codeverifier4RA' from origin 'https://client2' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> )

Interestingly, I have a controller with an endpoint (/hello) that returns strings, and I'm not encountering CORS issues for this endpoint. I've verified that the response headers are being set properly, as configured in my CORSFilter class.

Comment: you have `http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());` which enables the built in CORS filter with default settings. you are then supplying a `CorsConfigurationSource` configuring the built in CorsFilter. But then, you are also supplying a second self built `CORSFilter`? why are you adding an additional self built filter? How to configure CORS is extremly well documented in the spring security docs, and is one of the most asked questions under the spring-security tags. Also if you read up on what CORS are and when it is applied, you will get the answer to your last question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, @Toerktumlare. I've removed the built-in CORS filter with default settings and the CorsConfigurationSource configuration. Currently, I only have my self-built CORS filter in place.Unfortunately, I'm still facing the same CORS issue when making requests to the /oauth2/token endpoint

Comment: first of all stack overflow is not a forum, so we can't have some sort of dialog in the comments. Second of all, everytime you change or do something you must update your question because understand stack overflow is a Q&A site, i can't guess what your code looks like now and its NOT a forum. Third, i would suggest that you do the opposite, remove everything custom, and then read the spring security documentation CORS chapter and make sure your code matches what is applied in the docs. Fourth, never ask a question without supplying proper spring security enabled debug logs.

Comment: i will not comment anything further until you have actually read the docs, and implemented things first in accordance to the docs, then we can start the troubleshooting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77054725/619830